# Finding The Conic Section Classification

Tags: calculus

I have started with $$x^2-2xy+y^2+y=0$$

Using eigenvectors and eigenvectors and completing the square I came to

$$(y'-\frac{1}{\sqrt{32}})^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}x'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{32}}$$

How can I conclude which conic section it is?

Comment: This looks like $u^2+v=0$, and that looks like a parabola.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Rotation_of_conic_sections

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes I am looking for the standard form

Comment: See whether this helps you: https://www.ck12.org/calculus/classifying-conic-sections/lesson/Classifying-Conic-Sections-ALG-II/

Answer (score 0):

*This answer expands on @labbhattacharjee's comment.*

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832616/discriminant-of-a-conic-section) Math SE post, you can use the equation to find the $A,B,C$ in the general form $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F$, then find the discriminant $B^2 - 4AC$.

In this case, we have $(-2)^2 - 4(1)(1)$ which equals $0$. Since $B^2 - 4AC = 0$, the equation represents a parabola. You can use this method quite easily with other equations as well.